# Jquery multiselect with drop down issue

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have used multiselect JQuery for the select box.
The issue is when I put this select box in the div tag, then it's looking like this
Image: http://prntscr.com/ehdvgx

I have tried some CSS like " z-index: 9999999 " but won't work.

So please help me to solve this issue.

**JS Code:**

```
$('#sch_resource').multipleSelect({
    filter: true,
    placeholder: "<?=_("Select Resources")?>"
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="smartwizard">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#step-1">Step 1<br /><small><?=_('What')?></Small></a></Li>
    <li><a href="#step-2">Step 2<br /><small><?=_('Where')?></small></a></li>
    <li><a href="#step-3">Step 3<br /><small><?=_('When')?></small></a></li>
    </ul>
     <div class="custom_scrollbar" style="overflow: auto;">
     <!-- STEP 1 -->
          <div id="step-1" class="wrapper"  > 
                 <select name="sch_resource" id="sch_resource" style="width: 98%; margin-bottom: 15px;"  multiple="multiple"></select>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
#sch_resource
{
   z-index:999999;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you share your tried code?

Comment: can you please share code or link?